# 'Fake' identity regarding the closure in the subspace topology

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I have the following argument which I encountered, and can't seem to find why it's not true:

Let $X$ be a topological space and let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty subsets of $X$. Then $\overline{A\cap B}^A=\overline{A\cap B}^X\cap A$.

**"Proof"**

$\overline{A\cap B}^A =\cap \{ F\subset A: \; F\supseteq A\cap B, F \text{ is closed in } A \}$.

Since $F$ is closed in $A$ if and only if $F=F'\cap A$ where $F$ is closed in $X$. Hence

$\overline{A\cap B}^A= \cap \{ F'\cap A: \; F'\supseteq A\cap B, F' \text{ is closed }\}= \Big( \cap \{ F': \; F'\supseteq A\cap B, F' \text{ is closed }\}\Big) \cap A $.

And using an equivalent characterization of the closure,

$ \cap \{ F': \; F'\supseteq A\cap B, F' \text{ is closed }\}=\overline{A\cap B} $.

And finally we conclude

$ \overline{A\cap B}^A=\overline{A\cap B}^X\cap A  $.

I can't seem to find where this argument falters, but this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524605/subspace-closure) makes me think that it's wrong, and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? In general $\overline{B}^A=\overline{B}^X\cap A$.

Comment: @Chrystomath I think your "in general remark" is wrong. When $X=\mathbb{R},$ $B=\mathbb{Q}$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$, this is not true. Which is why I think my identity is wrong.

Comment: Why? What is $A$?

Comment: @Chrystomath  $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$ for example.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268943/closure-of-a-subset-of-a-subspace-of-a-topological-space#268945

Comment: Then $\overline{\varnothing}^A=\varnothing=\overline{\varnothing}^X\cap A$

Comment: @Chrystomath But $B\neq \emptyset$ and $\overline{B}^X=X$ in my case.

Comment: If $A=\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ and $B=\mathbb{Q}$ then $A\cap B=\varnothing$ not $B$.

Comment: That thread is different. It says $\overline{A\cap B}^A=\overline{B}^X\cap A$.

Comment: Read carefully the difference between the question you linked and yours.  In your notation, it is claiming that $\overline{A \cap B}^A = \overline{B}^X \cap A$ which is false.  You are claiming instead that $\overline{A \cap B}^A = \overline{A \cap B}^X \cap A$ which is true.

Comment: $\overline B^A=\overline B^X\cap A$ when $B\subseteq A.$ But $\overline B^A$ is meaningless when $B\not\subseteq A.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this answers your question but in general if $D\subseteq A$ then $\overline D^A=A\cap\overline D$.

---

Proof:

Observe that $A\cap\overline D$ is closed in $A$ with $D\subseteq A\cap\overline D$ telling us that $\overline D^A\subseteq A\cap\overline D$.

Conversely $\overline D^A$ is closed in $A$ so that $\overline D^A=A\cap F$ for some closed set $F$.

Then from $D\subseteq\overline D^A$  it follows that $D\subseteq F$ and consequently $\overline D\subseteq F$.

Then $A\cap\overline D\subseteq A\cap F=\overline D^A$.

---

Applying this on $D:=A\cap B$ we find the statement in your question.

Comment: So you think the statement is true?

Comment: Indeed. The statement is true.

Comment: Just one last thing, do you think the reasoning I wrote is generally sound?

Comment: If I read it correctly then you state:$$\overline{A\cap B}^{A}=\bigcap\left\{ A\cap F'\mid F'\text{ closed and }A\cap B\subseteq F'\right\} =A\cap\bigcap\left\{ F'\mid F'\text{ closed and }A\cap B\subseteq F'\right\} =A\cap\overline{A\cap B}$$This is sound.